# How to list all cloud services in Azure PowerShell, and then loop each cloud service to find how many VMs are in it

Tags: azure-powershell

I want to export an XML file which is contains all the cloud services and the VMs in each cloud service.

Comment: $ServiceList = Get-AzureService   
foreach ( $service in $ServiceList  )
{
       $vmList=Get-AzureVM -ServiceName $service.ServiceName
       foreach($vm in $vmList)
       { ........}
}
 I tried this Script and and then build a Xml file ,I think I find my way;is there other way for short?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would only call `Get-AzureVM` once to optimize processing. Afterwards I would group and output with PowerShell commands which are faster than filtering with the Azure PowerShell commands.

And with the grouping you also get an answer to your question in your title: how many VMs are in the Cloud Service? This is simply to get from the Count property.

```
$allVMs = Get-AzureVM

$allVMs | Group-Object -Property ServiceName

<# Output
Count Name                      Group                                                                                                                                 
----- ----                      -----                                                                                                                                 
    2 pksttest1                 {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.Model.PersistentVMRoleListContext, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManage...
    1 pksttest2                 {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.Model.PersistentVMRoleListContext}                                                 
#>

$services = Get-AzureVM | Group-Object -Property ServiceName

foreach ($service in $services) {
    # Output cloud service name
    "Cloud Service '$($service.Name)'"

    # Output VMs in that cloud service
    foreach ($vm in $service.Group) {
        "VM '$($vm.HostName)'"
    }
}

<# Output
Cloud Service 'pksttest1'
VM 'host1'
VM 'host3'
Cloud Service 'pksttest2'
VM 'host2'
#>
```

In your sample you call the Azure Service Management API once to get all cloud services and then again for every cloud service to get the VMs. With `Get-AzureVM` you get already all necessary data.

I also published the sample snippet on GitHub Gist: https://gist.github.com/pkirch/1ec6f3c1ca057b8beefb

Comment: Thank you very much,it's really a big help for me ,I'm from Beijing of China,and the Microsoft Azure is not so popular so I can hardly find help from people beside me or webset. And Now I want to find vm by subnet in the azure powershell ,can you show me a way !